# Tippy.js: Unable to disable tooltips

Tags: tippyjs

I want to disable tippy when on mobile. For this I have the following script. I use it like explained in the documentation of tippy:

```
const mytippies  = tippy('[data-tippy-content]', {
    plugins: [hideOnEsc],
});

mytippies.disable();
```

Doing this I get error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , o.default)(...).disable is not a function` what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the instance `mytippies` is an array of instances. The `disable` method only works on a single instance. So using a for loop I can disable Tippy for all my instances:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mytippies.length; i++) {
     mytippies[i].disable();
}
```