# Tippy.js - unable to destroy old tooltips

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

I've been creating a dynamic tippy tooltip. Every time a button is clicked, the content of the tooltip should change. What happens - every time a button is clicked, new tooltip is created and both of them are opened on hover.

My code:

HTML

```
<button>Button</button>

<div id="1" style="display:none"><span>Some text here</span></br><span>and here</span></div>
<div id="2" style="display:none"><span>Over</span></br></div>
```

JS

```
let idIndex = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  tippy('button')[0].destroy();
  idIndex++;
  const content = document.getElementById(`${idIndex}`).innerHTML
  console.log(content);
  tippy('button', {
   allowHTML: true,
   animation: 'shift-away',
   interactive: true,
   content: content,
   maxWidth: 600,
  });

})
```

I've tried destroying or disabling all the tooltips using loop [Tippy.js: Unable to disable tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991909/tippy-js-unable-to-disable-tooltips), but nothing helped.

Comment: Can your show us what gives  console.log(tippy('button')) after tippy('button')[0].destroy();?

Comment: @NicoZimmer it returns an array with one tippy object, it's methods. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I would have thought that destroy() would also remove the object from the array. If there is still an object, either the destroy() doesn't work, or you have 2 objects.